# Intl.Collator in javascript does not sort case sensitive the same as native array sort

Tags: javascript, sorting, internationalization

Why does using `Intl.Collator` with `sensitivity` option of `'case'` (i.e. case sensitivity is on) result in `aa` coming before `AA`?

When using the native `array.sort()` the ordering is as I would expect.

```js
const caseSensitiveCollator = new Intl.Collator('en',  { sensitivity: 'case' });

const initialData = ['AA', 'aa', 'ab', 'AB', 'ZA', 'zz'];
console.log('Before: ', initialData);

let data = initialData.concat();
data.sort(caseSensitiveCollator.compare);
console.log('After SENSITIVE', data);
// I expect ['AA', 'AB', 'ZA', 'aa', 'ab', 'zz']

data = initialData.concat().sort();
console.log('Native Array Sort', data);
```